# Jquery - how to reset value after empty input

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using jquery ui autocomplete And it works well for me But when I empty the field, the ID remains in the value I want the value to be empty after emptying the field

for example:[image]

after empty field:

[image]

script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#userName_search" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 500,

        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{ route('admin.autocomplete.search') }}",
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                    search: request.term
                },

                success: function( data ) {
                    response( data );
                }
            });
        },

        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#userName_search').val(ui.item.label) // display the selected text
            $('#id').val(ui.item.value).attr('value',ui.item.value);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `keyup` event, you can check for the value of the element`#userName_search`, and if it's empty you can clear the other element `#id`

```
    $("#userName_search").keyup(function() {    
        if (!this.value) {
          $("#id").val("");
        }
    
    });
```